# extracting public key from certificate and encrypting data

Tags: python, network-programming, rsa, pyopenssl

This is for a homework assignment!
I get the server's certificate using `get_peer_certificate()`
and the calling `dump_certificate` to dump the certificate in a variable. The format is PEM and looks right to me.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
GIBBERISH................
......................
........................

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How do I extract the server's public key from this file ('server.pubkey') and encrypt `plaintext` using `RSA` algorithm and any python library. At the time of writing this, I am using pyOpenSSL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend using a more broad [crypto library such as M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) which has the X509 certificate functions as well as RSA encryption:

```
from M2Crypto import RSA, X509
data = ssl_sock.getpeercert(1)
# load the certificate into M2Crypto to manipulate it
cert = X509.load_cert_string(data, X509.FORMAT_DER)
pub_key = cert.get_pubkey()
rsa_key = pub_key.get_rsa()
cipher = rsa_key.public_encrypt('plaintext', RSA.pkcs1_padding)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    from OpenSSL import crypto        
    crtObj = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, config.x509_certificate)
    pubKeyObject = crtObj.get_pubkey()
    pubKeyString = crypto.dump_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pubKeyObject)
```

Comment: What library does this use?

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder, It is from OpenSSL. updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate

cert_str = b"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----MIIDETCCAfm..."
cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_str)
public_key = cert_obj.public_key()
private_key = cert_obj.private_key()
```

Source: https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that [OpenSSL library](https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/) is not recommended to be used for those purposes. Instead, [cryptography library](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) is pointed. It is maintained and regularly updated.

Assuming you have the certificate in Pem format, the following code block will give you public key in string.

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

def read_pub_key_from_cert()
    # Read certificate file.
    with open("tls.crt") as certificate:
        cert = certificate.read()

    # Convert it into bytes.
    cert_in_bytes = bytes(cert, 'utf-8')

    # Create x509 certificate object.
    cert_obj = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_in_bytes)

    # Create Public key object.
    public_key_obj = cert_obj.public_key()

    # Convert Public key object into Pem format in bytes.
    public_pem = public_key_obj.public_bytes(
                    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
    )
    # Convert Public key into string.
    pub_key_string = public_pem.decode("utf-8")

    return(pub_key_string)
```